# How To count age from date of birth

Tags: momentjs

I am using moment.js with angular, how to get age in years, month and days. here is my code:

```
getAge(date) {
    let age = moment().diff(date, 'year');
    return age;
}
```

but it can give age only by year. How to get the age in years,days and month?

Comment: Please be more clear with what you need. It will only count from the year of the date because you have specified the format to be 'year'

Comment: @Charlie I want to get age by count year month and day.

Comment: By writing `diff(date, 'year')` you are reducing `date` to just it's year. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Charlie I kw that is counting only year please tell me the way how to get proper age by counting day, month and year

Answer (score 1):

```
var m1 = moment();
var m2 = moment(DATE OF BIRTH,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
var diff = moment.preciseDiff(m1, m2); // '1 month 2 days 3 hours 4 minutes 5 seconds'
```

This requires moment-precise-range.js to be included. For a detailed example, check this here - https://codebox.org.uk/pages/moment-date-range-plugin